# Usability improvements for the FAQ

Tags: discussion, site-faq

I believe some parts of the answer for [What kind of questions can I ask here](https://askubuntu.com/faq#questions) should actually be under the [What kind of questions should I not ask here?](https://askubuntu.com/faq#dontask)

Specifically, the part about *This is not the right place for* should be better placed under the next section.[image]

I hope this will give the new users a better glance of what not to ask in the site. Any thoughts on whether the content should be moved or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been requested multiple times on meta.so, however Moderators can *only* edit the What kind of questions can I ask here portion of the faq

Comment: I think we can only hope we can edit that part eventually. :/